# php repeat function 10 times if value is comma

Tags: php, coordinates, repeat

I'm trying to repeat the function only if the value is ",":

This is my code for trying to get the coordinates from an address but somtimes it gets only "," so I want it to try 10 times until it gets the full coordinates.

```
$coordinates1 = getCoordinates($placeadress); 
$i == 0;
while (($coordinates1 == ',') && ($i <= 10)) {
    $coordinates1 = getCoordinates($placeadress);
    $i++;
}
```

The function code is this:

```
function getCoordinates($address) {
    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with "+" sign to match with google search pattern
    $address = str_replace("-", "+", $address); // replace all the "-"  with "+" sign to match with google search pattern
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web
    return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);
}
```

Comment: Okay, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't really know if this code is correct

Comment: What's it supposed to do, and what does it do?

Comment: Why do you have to repeatedly call the function getCoordinates?

Comment: The return is "," and it supposed to return "31.8232966,34.6994269" (for exxample).

Comment: i think youre getting the coma because $placeAddress variable has a lot of comas. ex.
postal code, country, state, street, internal number, external number,  
maybe if postal code in address is missing. you only read a coma.

Comment: Can you show example input and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to understand, does your 'function' sometimes return a different value with the same input?

Comment: What is $i == 0; ?

Comment: Yes, the function gets a different value for the same input address, so i wanted to repeat this action until it gets the right value

Comment: @DigiNet Events What $placeadress are you testing with?

Comment: HaYarkon Street, Tel-Aviv, Israel

Answer (score 0):

May be try this

```
$coordinates1 = getCoordinates($placeadress); 
$i = 0;
    while ($i <= 10) {
    $coordinates1 = getCoordinates($placeadress);
    if($coordinates1==',')
        $i++;
    else
        break;
    }
```

It will break the loop as soon as co-ordinates value is not a comma and you are good to go. If it is a comma it will go for next iteration in while

Answer (score 0):

You could just reduce all that code to a while with an empty block:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (
    ($coords = getLatLong($place))
    && $coords == ','
    && $i++ < 10
);
```

There's still perhaps no guarantee of the 'right' value being returned even after calling the function 10 times.